# Azure Front Door is no allowing create a azure manage https certificate

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have a Front Door instance working, with a custom domain setup and azure front door is managing the certificate for me. However, I was trying to add a second custom domain and every time I select CUSTOM DOMAIN HTTPS -> enable, then, select azure front door to manage my certificate and click save, after a few minutes I get this error:

```
Failed to update the custom https configuration for the frontend host ''. Error: Sorry, it looks like there was an error on our end. Please contact Support if you keep having this problem.
```

I have tried creating another Front door instance but the result is the same is not letting me add a certificate to the custom domain. I have tried using my own certificate and the result is the same.

The custom domain is being validated with a CNAME register the dns

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution for this? I have the very same issue